# Is stringbuilder necessary anymore?

Tags: c#, string, clr, stringbuilder, cil

We all know that concatenating strings can cause efficiency problems, especially in loops. I was taught to use `StringBuilder` to prevent these problems.

So this:

```
str += someotherstring
```

Turns into this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
sb.AppendLine(someotherstring);
```

But it is my understanding that the CLR in the .NET framework 3.5 and later is smart enough to output the same IL for both approaches. So is there a reason I should be enforcing stringbuilder in my teams code reviews anymore?

**Edit**: I think **Servy** hit the nail on the head in the comments:

> This is the case when concatenating a number of strings *known* at compile time. Because of that, when concatenating a number of strings known at compile time there is no need to use a SB. When concatenating a number of strings *unknown* at compile time, it cannot do that

Comment: The CLR doesn't output IL, that's a compiler's job.

Comment: Try profiling `var rnd = new Random(); var str = ""; for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) { str += rnd.Next().ToString(); }` versus `var rnd = new Random(); var sb = new StringBuilder(); for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) { sb.Append(rnd.Next().ToString()); } var str = sb.ToString();`

Comment: Do you have any resource that claims both outputs same IL above .net 3.5?

Comment: _"One of the first pieces of efficiency advice most .NET developers learn is: use StringBuilder to concatenate strings. This is a misunderstood piece of received wisdom."_ http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Well, of course. Concatenating "Hello " and "World!" with a StringBuilder is stupid. But concatenating a unknown and/or potentially large number of strings *without* a StringBuilder is even more stupid.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That *doesn't* mean that SB doesn't serve a purpose and should be removed.  It just means that it's a bit more complicated than that to determine when it should be used, and many people don't understand them.  It's still very important for the type to exist, because it's implementation is *very* different from standard string concatenation.

Comment: @Servy: I havent said that it should not be used but the whole point of the OP is that it should be used everytime in a loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Um..no.  The title is "Is stringbuilder necessary anymore".  The OP seems to be under the impression that SB should never ever be used anymore because standard string concatenation will always be at least as good.  That is false.

Comment: @Servy: He was told to use `StringBuilder` in loops. Now he asks if he still needs to use it or if it will be used implicitely. So imho the answer "No,  `StringBuilder` will not be used implcitely" will lead to the conclusion that he still needs to use it when he concatenates strings. But that's _not always_ the best idea in terms of readability and performance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The answer to the question of "should I stop using SB entirely" is simple, "no, don't stop using it entirely, use it in the situations in which it is appropriate, which is some of the time, but not all of the time."  If he doesn't know when it is and isn't appropriate, that's a common enough question that has several duplicates, and several good blogs on the subject linked in this question already.

Comment: @sriram - "if you examine the IL behind the scenes.  Whenever you do a string.Concat() – or operator + of course - in your code, it examines the lengths of the arguments and creates a StringBuilder behind the scenes of the appropriate size for you." http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx

Comment: @Coltech That is the case *when concatenating a number of strings known at compile time*.  Because of that, when concatenating a number of strings known at compile time there is no need to use a SB.  When concatenating a number of strings *unknown* at compile time, it cannot do that.  If SB semantics are important in such a case (namely, that you have enough data for performance to matter) you should almost certainly be using a SB or similar means of avoiding naive concatenation.

Answer (score 7):

No that is not always correct. I dont if you have check this [How to improve string concatenation performance in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822)

> However, the .NET Framework includes a StringBuilder class that is
>   optimized for string concatenation. It provides the same benefits as
>   using a character array in C/C++, as well as automatically growing the
>   buffer size (if needed) and tracking the length for you. The sample
>   application in this article demonstrates the use of the StringBuilder
>   class and compares the performance to concatenation.

StringBuilder is preferable when you are doing multiple loops, or forks in your code pass.

Also check this

## **[StringBuilder is not always faster – Part 1 of 2](http://www.chinhdo.com/20070224/stringbuilder-is-not-always-faster/)**

> This block of code took 1484 milliseconds to run on my PC:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)  { 
>     // Concat strings 3 times using StringBuilder 
>     StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); 
>     s.Append(i.ToString()); 
>     s.Append(i.ToString()); 
>     s.Append(i.ToString());  }
> ```
>
> And this one, using traditional concatenation, took slightly less
>   time (1344 milliseconds):
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)  { 
>     // Concat strings 3 times using traditional concatenation 
>     string s = i.ToString(); 
>     s = s + i.ToString(); 
>     s = s + i.ToString();  }
> ```
>
> **The above data suggests that StringBuilder only starts to work faster
>   once the number of concatenations exceed 3.**

There is great link in comments posted by Tim which says about the

## **[Rules of Thumb](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)**

> **So, when should you use StringBuilder, and when should you use the
>   string concatenation operators?**
>
> - Definitely use StringBuilder when you're concatenating in a    non-trivial loop - especially if you don't know for sure (at compile
>     time) how many iterations you'll make through the loop. **For example,
>     reading a file a character at a time, building up a string as you go
>     using the += operator is potentially performance suicide.**
> - Definitely use the concatenation operator when you can (readably) specify everything which needs to be concatenated in one statement.
>     (If you have an array of things to concatenate, consider calling
>     String.Concat explicitly - or String.Join if you need a delimiter.)
> - Don't be afraid to break literals up into several concatenated bits -    the result will be the same. You can aid readability by breaking a    long literal into several lines, for instance, with no harm to
>     performance.
> - If you need the intermediate results of the concatenation for    something other than feeding the next iteration of concatenation,
>     StringBuilder isn't going to help you. For instance, if you build up
>     a full name from a first name and a last name, and then add a third
>     piece of information (the nickname, maybe) to the end, you'll only
>     benefit from using StringBuilder if you don't need the (first name +
>     last name) string for other purpose (as we do in the example which
>     creates a Person object).
> - If you just have a few concatenations to do, and you really want to    do them in separate statements, it doesn't really matter which way
>     you go. Which way is more efficient will depend on the number of
>     concatenations the sizes of string involved, and what order they're
>     concatenated in. If you really believe that piece of code to be a 
>     performance bottleneck, profile or benchmark it both ways.

Comment: It's not just the number of concatenations, it's also the size of the strings.  Standard string concatentation involved constantly re-creating new buffers and copying the string data over.  If the strings are a few thousand characters long, even a few of them involves a lot of duplicate copying.  If they are tiny, the wasted effort is much smaller.

Comment: So saying you should use a SB when concatenating more than 3 strings is incorrect and misleading.  The number of strings being concatted is not the sole factor to be considered, it is just one of several.

Comment: Yes I agree that there can be more factors then just contenating 3 or more strings. It is just that I took one from all of them. Although updating the misleading part

Comment: The increased performance when using a StringBuilder instead of using String concatenation comes from lower heap pressure. When concatenating Strings you allocate possibly lots of temporary String objects that have to be collected the next time the GC kicks in. Your performance comparison is fairly useless, as it doesn't measure the actual difference (lower heap pressure, less GC cycles).

Comment: @Servy: Appending strings using a `StringBuilder` will require at minimum an allocation for the StringBuilder's buffer and another for the final string; every character be copied into the buffer, and later to the resulting string.  Thus, joining two strings and as a separate step adding a third will be better with ordinary strings than with a StringBuilder, since each character in the first two strings will end up getting copied twice using strings, and at least twice with `StringBuilder`; characters in the last string will copied once using strings, or twice with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: For usage of `StringBuilder` to be a win, it must avoid the allocation of at least two intermediate strings.  If strings are small, more than two intermediate allocations will need to be avoided to overcome the overhead of `StringBuilder`, but in cases where only one intermediate string would be used, `StringBuidler` is a loser regardless of string size.

Answer (score 2):

> But it is my understanding that the CLR in the .NET framework 3.5 and
>   later is smart enough to output the same IL for both approaches.

**No.** That is not necessary. You can't rely on compiler to optimize this in a loop. It is also better to use `StringBuilder` since it will definitely be better in string concatenation and provides better readability.

Comment: Although I agree with most of your answer, 'better readability' is preference. I prefer the readability of standard concatenation.

Comment: You give an answer but site no sources and give no reason as to why.This article seems to have a different opion http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: Not only Jeff Atwood but also Jon Skeet. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html You should not generalize things too much.

Comment: @Coltech That source is saying that if the data set is small enough it's not worth considering performance.  That doesn't mean that performance never ever matters, just that it doesn't *always* matter.  Having a SB is still an important tool that is absolutely essential in certain contexts.

Comment: @Coltech That source also says that it didn't even bother to measure the performance: *"I didn't get a chance to run these against CLRProfiler to see if there was a clear winner in that regard [memory consumption]. It's a valid point, but I doubt the results would change much."* While I do highly value Jeff Atwood's opinions he is so awfully wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` will be used when you're concatenating an arbitrary amount of string values, for example. If this scenario sounds like your scenario then, yes, you should enforce the use of `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in .NET are *immutable*. Once constructed they cannot be modified later. If you want to modify a string you need to create a new one from the old one and throw away the old one.

A StringBuilder on the other hand can be thought of as a *mutable* string. Changing its contents after it is constructed is possible, and does not require allocating a whole new object.

The different performance characteristics usually do not surface when comparing the time taken to perform similar operations using a StringBuilder and string concatenation. The effect is more indirect: While string concatenation produces potentially lots of short-lived temporary objects, the StringBuilder doesn't. Consequently, using a StringBuilder can significantly reduce memory pressure on the managed heap, reducing the necessity for costly garbage collections.

It all depends on your application though and I will not try to give any generic advice. An application that performs a lot of string manipulations (like a web server) needs more attention than one that doesn't. If you understand how strings and a StringBuilder are different and the implications you should be in a good position to make judicious decisions. If in doubt: profile. But be sure to profile GC cycles as well.